# Flutter: How to animate the camera of Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to build an app that loads a GoogleMap(), then after getting the user latitude and longitude moves to the that specific location.

I came up with this idea (code below), but it works only if I restart the app and if I don't it gives error: animateCamera was called on null.

How is it possible ? and how can i fix it ?

Thanks for answering :D

```js
...

var mapController;

...

GoogleMap createMap() {
    var initMap = GoogleMap(
      onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
      initialCameraPosition:
          CameraPosition(target: LatLng(47.290542, 8.322641), zoom: 6.7),
    );
    return initMap;
  }
  
  ...

  void onMapCreated(controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }
 
 ...
 
   void moveCameraToUserLocation(searchedLocation2) async {
    var location = await Geocode().getLatLng(searchedLocation2);
    print("moving to: $location");
    mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          target: location,
          zoom: 20,
        ),
      ),
    );
    
 ...
 
 build(context) {

    return Scaffold(

      body: createMap(),

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on how you describe the problem, it looks like you are only calling the animate function as the map loads.

---

I suggest that you create a button that would handle and trigger the animate function and move the camera to the device location whenever tapped.

The following code snippet uses a `ClipOval` button and inside the `OnTap()` event you can call the method to get the device current location which will be triggered whenever the button is tapped.

```
ClipOval(
   child: Material(
   color: Colors.green[100], // button color
   child: InkWell(
   splashColor: Colors.green, // inkwell color
   child: SizedBox(
   width: 56,
   height: 56,
   child: Icon(Icons.my_location),
   ),
   onTap: () {

    // Add methods here that will be called whenever the button is tapped 

    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(_currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude),
    zoom: 17.0)));
    setState(() {
    allMarkers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('Current Position'),
      draggable: false,
      position:
          LatLng(_currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude)));
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are calling moveCameraToUserLocation function before map is created. From this part of the code I cannot se when you call thi function but my guess is that you call it from initstate. If you want to call this function immediately after widget is created move it to onMapCreated.

```
void onMapCreated(controller) {
   mapController = controller;
   moveCameraToUserLocation();
}
```